# Ionic push notifications how to trigger onNotification event if app is in the background?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to trigger **onNotification** event if app is running in the background.

**I tried to do it by this way:**

```
$ionicPush.init({
        "canShowAlert": true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
        "canSetBadge": true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
        "canPlaySound": true, //Can notifications play a sound?
        "canRunActionsOnWake": true, //Can run actions outside the app,
        "debug": true,
        "onNotification": function (notification) {
          console.log("onNotification");
          var payload = notification.payload;
          console.log(notification);
          var title = "SmartCam mobile";
          var message = $translate.instant('Cam') + " : " + $translate.instant(payload.eventType) + " " + $translate.instant("registered at") + " " + payload.time;
          notificationService.showNotification(title, message, payload);
        },
        "onRegister": function (data) {
          console.log("onRegister");
          console.log(data.token);
          localStorageService.set("STORED_VALUES_PUSH_TOKEN", data.token);
          localStorageService.set("STORED_VALUES_PLATFORM", ionic.Platform.platform().toLowerCase());
        }
      });
```

A used attribute content_available: 1 in push request too:

```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xyz" -d '
    {
        "tokens": ["abc"],
        "profile": "smartcam",
        "notification": {
            "title": "Push sssTitle",
            "message": "Push sotification body",
            "content_available": 1,
            "payload": {
                "baz": "boo"
            },
            "android": {
                "title": "Hey",
                "message": "Hello Android!",
                "content_available": 1,
                "payload": {
                    "baz": "boo"
                }
              },
           "ios": {
                "title": "Howdy",
                "message": "Hello iOS!",
                "content_available": 1,
                "payload": {
                    "baz": "boo"
                }
              }
        }
    }' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

But without the luck.

How can i trigger this event if app is running in the background?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to remove the "title" attribute from the "android" and "ios".

Also, you'll need to make sure you have ran this on your ionic project:

ionic config set dev_push false